# Gradle test library in multi module project

Tags: gradle

I want to create a library that other modules in my project can depend on, but only for tests. I've read the Gradle documentation extensively and couldn't find how to do it. This is my project structure:

```
gradle-example:
  app:
    src/main/kotlin ...
    src/test/kotlin <- this is supposed to use 'com.example.SomeTestUtil'
  testlib:
    src/test/kotlin/com.example.SomeTestUtil
```

settings.gradle.kts:

```
rootProject.name = "gradle-example"
include("app")
include("testlib")
```

In the app module I tried adding

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation(project(:testlib"))
}
```

But I get compilation error trying to import the `SomeTestUtil` in the `app` module test classes.

What is the correct way to declare dependency on a module in the same project that allows to use test sources in test code?

To clarify, we want to create a library that can **only** be used by other modules under `src/test` and not `src/main`.

Comment: When you have test-specific code anywhere below `main`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm not sure I understand. This is exactly the situation I'm trying to avoid, I want to encapsulate test code to test sources only via a shared test library, and never let it pollute any production code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this can be done by using the https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures

> - they can see the main source set classes
> - test sources can see the test fixtures classes

So changes to the example in the question are:

1. changing the `src/test` to `src/testFixtures`
2. declaring the dependency as `testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":testlib")))`
3. Adding `java-test-fixtures` plugin to the `build.gradle.kts` for the `testlib` module

Comment: Is this working with Kotlin?